# MySql query to find rooms available given dates 'From' and 'to'

Tags: mysql, sql

Tables are as follows

```
rooms(RoomId(PK)(int),
      RoomName(varchar))

bookings(RoomId(FK)(int),
         From_D(date),
         To_D(date),
         Bookee(varchar))

(PK-primary Key ,FK-foreign Key)
```

Given the `arrival(From_D)` and `departure(To_D)` dates how do i find out the id of the rooms that are available

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RoomId 
FROM bookings 
WHERE  arrival not in(From_D,To_d) AND 
       departure not in(From_D,To_d)
```

But seeing the structure of my DB problem occurs if there multiple booking of a room stored in the DB, and it books the room even if it was not free in that range of dates

Comment: please provide sample data and your expected output in table format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following diagram (sorry for bad handwriting):

[image]

In the above diagram, we can see date ranges on a horizontal axis. `From_D` to `To_D` represents a booked slot for a specific room. Four cases are considered for Arrival and Departure dates (denoted by A<sub>i</sub> and D<sub>i</sub>).

We can clearly see that a particular room is available *only* when the arrival and departure dates are either completely on the left side, or the right side of the booked slot.

We can `GROUP BY` on `RoomID` and consider only those rooms, where every booking for follows the criteria defined above, using the `HAVING` clause.

The query would be simply the following:

```
SELECT RoomID 
FROM bookings 
GROUP BY RoomID 
HAVING 
  SUM((From_D < :arrival AND To_D < :arrival) 
             OR 
      (From_D > :departure AND To_D > :departure)) = COUNT(*)
```

---

[**Demo on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jDxU2Z5HLJzRwpQieezwgF/2)

```
CREATE TABLE `rooms` (
 `RoomId` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `RoomName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`RoomId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
 `RoomId` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `From_D` date NOT NULL,
 `To_d` date NOT NULL,
 `B_Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 KEY `RoomId` (`RoomId`),
 CONSTRAINT `bookings_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`RoomId`) REFERENCES `rooms` (`RoomId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `rooms` (`RoomId`, `RoomName`) VALUES 
('1', 'Auditorium'), 
('2', 'Room2'), 
('3', 'Room3'), 
('4', 'Room4'), 
('5', 'Room5');

INSERT INTO `bookings` (`RoomId`, `From_D`, `To_d`, `B_Name`) VALUES 
('1', '2018-11-01', '2018-11-03', 'Trance'), 
('2', '2018-11-02', '2018-11-07', 'Alcoding'), 
('3', '2018-11-01', '2018-11-04', 'DebSoc'), 
('4', '2018-11-12', '2018-11-17', 'MunSoc'), 
('5', '2018-11-03', '2018-11-06', 'Pulse');
```

**Query:** Check for any availability between 2018-11-01 and 2018-11-03

```
SELECT RoomId 
FROM bookings 
GROUP BY RoomID 
HAVING 
  SUM((From_D < '2018-11-01' AND To_D < '2018-11-01') 
             OR 
      (From_D > '2018-11-03' AND To_D > '2018-11-03')) = COUNT(*)
```

**Result:** Only RoomId 4 is available as per the sample data

```
| RoomId |
| ------ |
| 4      |
```

Comment: I tried running this query but it returns zero rows for dates in which some rooms are free

Comment: @TanmayShrivastava can you please provide the SQL for the sample data in the table, in which this query is failing

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT b1.RoomId 
FROM bookings AS b1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
                   SELECT 1 
                   FROM bookings AS b2 
                   WHERE b2.RoomId = b1.RoomId 
                     AND  NOT('2018-11-01'< b2.From_D AND '2018-11-03' < b2.From_D) 
                                  OR 
                          NOT('2018-11-01' > b2.To_D AND '2018-11-03' > b2.To_D)
                 )`

Comment: i know that there is a room that is free between the dates given but the query returns zero results

Comment: @TanmayShrivastava please provide the  sample data in which this query is failing.

Comment: INSERT INTO `rooms` (`RoomId`, `RoomName`) VALUES ('1', 'Auditorium'), ('2', 'Room2'), ('3', 'Room3'), ('4', 'Room4'), ('5', 'Room5');

INSERT INTO `bookings` (`RoomId`, `From_D`, `To_d`, `B_Name`) VALUES ('1', '2018-11-01', '2018-11-03', 'Trance'), ('2', '2018-11-02', '2018-11-07', 'Alcoding'), ('3', '2018-11-01', '2018-11-04', 'DebSoc'), ('4', '2018-11-12', '2018-11-17', 'MunSoc'), ('5', '2018-11-03', '2018-11-06', 'Pulse');

Comment: Done ,I have set the data up

Comment: @TanmayShrivastava In that url, click on Save button, it will generate a new link. Please share the link here

Comment: @TanmayShrivastava please check the updated answer. Here is the working fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jDxU2Z5HLJzRwpQieezwgF/2

Answer (score 0):

Use **BETWEEN** and **AND** with your date

```
SELECT DISTINCT RoomId FROM bookings    
WHERE (date_field BETWEEN From_D AND To_d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct r.*
from rooms r
    left join bookings b on b.RoomId=r.RoomId
where b.RoomId is null or @arrival > To_D or @departure < from_td
```

Comment: answer with only code are poor, can you please explain what your code does?

Comment: What should `@arrival` do? That does not look like valid SQL

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this :
    SELECT * FROM   rooms room1
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM   booking booking1
                       WHERE  room1.roomid = booking1.roomid AND
                              (:from_d BETWEEN booking1.from_d AND booking1.to_d OR
                               :to_d   BETWEEN booking1.from_d AND booking1.to_d))
```