# mysql select time interval that does not fall under a given interval

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have the following table

```
+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
| class_id | teacher_id | starts_at | ends_at  |
+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
|       39 |          5 | 15:00:00  | 21:00:00 |
|       40 |         20 | 18:00:00  | 21:00:00 |
|       41 |         59 | 18:00:00  | 21:00:00 |
|       42 |         21 | 18:30:00  | 20:00:00 |
|       43 |         80 | 18:30:00  | 21:00:00 |
|       44 |       NULL | 17:30:00  | 21:00:00 |
|       45 |        140 | 17:30:00  | 20:00:00 |
|       46 |        123 | 18:30:00  | 21:00:00 |
+----------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

For a particular instance, I do not have any teacher available in hand but I need to select those teacher whose class timings do not fall under a certain given time. For example. A new class (class_id=47) has been announced with a timing of `15:00:00` to `17:30:00`. Now I want to select the `teacher_id`'s, who's existing class timings do not fall under this interval. How should I write this query?

Tried this but I was wrong:

```
SELECT * from classes 
where time(starts_at) not between '15:00:00' and '17:30:00' 
and time(ends_at) not between '15:00:00' and '17:30:00'
```

Comment: This will fail when start and end time lies on either side of the time range. Check this answer for an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53319378/2469308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the overlapping range problem.  You may use the following logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM classes 
WHERE '15:00:00' >= ends_at OR '17:30:00' <= starts_at;
```

[image]

### Demo

The logic I used is borrowed from the canonical question [Check overlap of date ranges in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545947/check-overlap-of-date-ranges-in-mysql)

To find records which overlap with a new incoming start and end time, we would use:

```
WHERE new_start < existing_end AND new_end > existing_start;
```

However, in your case, you want ranges which have zero overlap, i.e. the opposite of the above.  By DeMorgan's laws, the above logic then becomes:

```
WHERE new_start >= existing_end AND new_end <= existing_start;
```